# How can I solve this problem about discord.js

Tags: discord.js

This is my code.

```
import { Client } from 'discord.js';

const client = new Client({ intents: ['Guilds', 'GuildMessages']})
const TOKEN = 'my token'

client.login(TOKEN);
```

I got this error

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\programing\bearbot> node .
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:423
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\dev\programing\bearbot\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:415:19)     
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:665:18)
    at resolveMainPath (node:internal/modules/run_main:15:25)   
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:24)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\dev\\programing\\bearbot\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\dev\\programing\\bearbot'
}

Node.js v20.9.0
```

How can I solve this problem

I want to know how I can solve this problem.
Please help me.

**Because I am Korean, the grammar of my question may be wrong. Sorry**

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize a package in your directory first.

run this command `npm init`

if that not still solve your problem you can remove your `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again.

Comment: I do that. but I can't solve this problem